# Second-hand products in GDP

Tags: gdp

I am aware that secondhand goods are not counted in GDP due to double counting issues, but I want to ask about a specific case of transaction of second-hand goods.

For instance, what if a student buys a book for 20$,

uses the book  for a bit, and then sells it to a college bookstore for

40$? And what if the college bookstore sells that used book to another

student for 50$?

I know that for the second case, the 10 $ (50 $ - 40 $) will be counted in

GDP because this represents the bookstore's services created for providing

books.

But what about the first scenario, where a student sold the book to the

bookstore for 40 $?

Would the 20 $ (40 $ - 20 $) be counted in GDP? Or would

this just count as the increase in the student's wealth?

Answer (score 1):

Its because the student did not produce any value added **in the production** of the book. She used the book and then basically transferred it to the bookstore. On the other hand, the bookstore may repair the book and sell it for a \$10 profit.  (the bookstore may be advertising, displaying, and other services). The \$10 reflects this additional value added in the economy in the current year, and is thus added to the current GDP.